# QNAP Find with printf

Tags: bash, find, printf

I'm trying to `printf` to a specific format (file path and last modified date) for archiving purposes but having issues with find on QNAP running BusyBox v1.24.1.

```
find . -type f -mtime -1825 -printf "%h%f %TD\n";
```

Error:

> find: unrecognized: -printf

It doesn't support `printf`, so i'm trying to use the `exec` parameter. With the following:

```
find . -type f -mtime -1825 -exec printf "%h%f %TD\n" {} \;
```

But now i get the following error:

> find: printf: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `find -printf` is used to show attributes of files, while POSIX `printf` is used to format/convert strings. They are not used for the same thing and can't be substituted for each other.

Instead, BusyBox has a `stat -c` you can use for some of the same things:

```
find . -type f -mtime -1825 -exec stat -c '%n %y' {} \;
```

Note that while the same information is present, it's formatted differently.

Comment: Thank you, this exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: do you know of a way of printing the complete file path and not just the file name?

Comment: @LeeStevens It repeats whatever you give it, so you can use `find "$PWD"` instead of `find .`

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` command is builtin to shells (per the POSIX spec) and is not an external utility. You can utilize it with `-exec` by spawning a shell:

```
find . -type f -mtime -1825 -exec sh -c 'printf "%h%f %TD\n" $1' sh {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you, but i was only outputting what the error was...
Your command doesn't seem to work to: "sh: line 0: printf: `%': invalid format character"